# ASP.net Visual Studio 2013 C# user already exists

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, ado.net

I have this piece of code to test in case the user already exists in the database

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
         ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AssignmentDBConnectionString"]
         .ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();

    //selects count from userdata and checks if username exists in the database
    string checkUser = "select count(*) from [AsTable] where Username ='" 
         + TextBoxUsername.Text + "'";

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    if (temp > 0)
    {
        Response.Write("User Already Exists");
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

However when I try to register an already existing user it doesn't display the user already exists message and throws this error

> InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
>   An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

And this is the stack trace

> [InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.]
>
> System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +5356096
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
>      System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +94
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +110
>      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>      Registration.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Michalis\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\Assignment - ASP\Registration.aspx.cs:40
>      System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
>      System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

Comment: Please post full stacktrace!

Comment: This code is bad in so many ways... Please, please, please read up on: `SqlParameter` to prevent SQL injection (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx#paght000002_step3), on casting to remove your need for `Convert.ToInt32(.ToString)` (http://fxcopcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DoNotUseParseAndTostringToConvertTypes&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: I suspect you need to replace [AsTable] with the actual name of the table that holds the users

Comment: AsTable is the table name that holds the users!! I have edited the post and included the whole error log that appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found It!! I declared temp above the page_load code and modified it like this

```
int temp = 0;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AssignmentDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string checkUser = "select count(*) from [AsTable] where Username ='" + TextBoxUsername.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        if (temp != 0)
        {
            Response.Write("User Already Exists");
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
 .
 .
```

Code that follows!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 if (IsPostBack)
 {
 int result = 0;
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AssignmentDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
     conn.Open();

//selects count from userdata and checks if username exists in the database
string checkUser = "select count(*) from [AsTable] where Username = @username";

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", TextBoxUsername.Text);
result = (int)com.ExecuteScalar()
if (result > 0)
{
    Response.Write("User Already Exists");
}
conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't throw the error now but it proceeds with the rest of the code and redirects the user to the login page!! In other words! It allows the user to register with the same username

Comment: I really dont know what you want to achieve. Kindly describe the algorithm you want to develop in a detailed manner. This program will really proceed to the succeeding code cause it doesn't have something to trigger a stop. What page does this code belong? Is it a login page? Home page? Register page? In my own understanding your on the register page then if the user exist it must not redirect to the login page. Is that what you want? Added additional info about your other codes could help us resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use return; after the check if it return exists thus it will stop executing the rest of your code.. good luck.